# HTML error code 206

Tags: javascript, html, web2py

When my application loads, it does not load the js files fully. I found it loads then partially, 
due to this application is not at all usable.

I have also found if there is good internet speed, this problem does not occur. It works fine with 8 Mbps connection.

I am using web2py framework.

Comment: how many js files are there and how big are they?

Comment: I am loading jquery.js, jquery-ui.js which are the lagest, some custom js which is small.

Comment: Try [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) and enable the console panel to see if it reports any errors.

Comment: Firebug shows error is different places, mostly function not found. All the errors are due to js file not loaded fully.

Answer (score 0):

Make a jsfiddle or put all the code here, otherwise we can't help you. You can also put the headers of the response.